# How to determine the maximum discount that a threshold percentage of a population received

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out what formula would help me find the maximum discount that a threshold percentage of a population received.

For example, in the table below, I want to know the the maximum discount received by at least 30% of the population.

```
Population   Discount
400          25%
3000         24%
2000         23%
1000         22%
850          20%
400          19%
350          18%
350          15%
1500         13%
450          12%
700          11%
3000         5%
7000         3%
6000         2%
```

This is easy enough if the data is sorted as above by discount amount in descending order.  It's simple enough to just go down the cumulative % of population from the top until at least 30% is reach then check the discount %.

In the table above, at least 30% of the population is reached at row 8 (30.93% of total population), so the maximum discount received for at least 30% of the population is 15%.

However, what if the data is not in that order?  How could I get to the same answer from the table below without being able to rely on sorting by highest discount first?

```
People   Discount
700      11%
3000     24%
3000     5%
1000     22%
6000     2%
400      25%
350      18%
350      15%
1500     13%
450      12%
850      20%
400      19%
7000     3%
2000     23%
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise to sort the data, that makes life soooo much easier. If it is important for you to maintain the current order, add a numbered helper column, so sorting on that column will put your data back in the original format.

Comment: Thanks, Luuklag.  The problem I have is that the actual source table is more complex than the example above and sorted by another column that makes the data easier for the end user to consume.  Unfortunately there are several such tables and every time the discount and population numbers change, I have to redo this task of altering the sort order by highest discount first then finding the max discount for X% of the population.  I am hoping to find a way to remove the monotony of that task.

Comment: Well that would very well be possible if you are willing to write the VBA code for that.

Comment: Power Query might be another option for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the aid of a helper column.

Define a helper column that gives how many people got that discount or better:

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:$A$15,$B$2:$B$15,">="&B2)
```

(assuming your data is in A1:B15). This gives you

```
People   Discount  Helper
700      11%       11000
3000     24%       3400
3000     5%        14000
1000     22%       6400
6000     2%        27000
400      25%       400
350      18%       8000
350      15%       8350
1500     13%       9850
450      12%       10300
850      20%       7250
400      19%       7650
7000     3%        21000
2000     23%       5400
```

Now what you want is to find the maximum discount in column B such that the value in column C is at least 30% of the total number of people.

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B15,C2:C15,">="&30%*SUM(A2:A15))
```

You can, if you'd like, make that hardcoded 30% into a cell reference that contains that parameter.

Comment: `MAXIFS` is available in Excel 2016 onwards. Different approach may be required for previous versions of Excel.